# Magento 2 help validate function to count bundle product child items of an order

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-items, custom-reports

I'm trying to write a function that takes an **order** object, and returns an array of sku => qty (key-value) showing how many of each sku was sold/shipped.

The tricky part is, magento formats line items differently on configurable and bundle products.

Example:

```
Line1: name shirt-X2, type bundle, ordered 2, shipped 2.
Line2: name shirt, type simple, ordered 4, shipped 0. // <-- my problem
```

I've written this code:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
 * @return array
 */
public function getOrderData($order)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getProductType() != 'simple') {
            continue;
        }
        $sku = $item->getSku();
        $orderedReal = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        $orderedB = $item->getQtyOrdered() - $item->getQtyRefunded() - $item->getQtyCanceled();
        $orderedB = max(round($orderedB, 8), 0);
        $invoicedB = $item->getQtyOrdered() - $item->getQtyInvoiced() - $item->getQtyCanceled();
        $invoicedB = max(round($invoicedB, 8), 0);
        $shippedReal = 0;
        $isShipped = false;
        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
            $parent = $item->getParentItem();
            if ($parent->getQtyOrdered() > 0 && $parent->getQtyOrdered() == $parent->getQtyShipped()) {
                $isShipped = true;
            }
        } else {
            if ($item->getQtyOrdered() > 0 && $item->getQtyOrdered() == $item->getQtyShipped()) {
                $isShipped = true;
            }
        }
        if ($isShipped) {
            $shippedReal = $orderedReal;
        }
        $result[] = [
            'sku' => $sku,
            'invoiced' => $invoicedB,
            'ordered' => $orderedB,
            'shipped' => $shippedReal
        ];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Is this function valid, or could it be improved ?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks